# How to Avoid Crashing of screen size when video is rotated

Tags: android, orientation, android-videoview, screen-orientation

i have problems in playing my video. I have an activity with the following property in manifest

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

but everytime i change the orientation from portrait to landscape, the screen size is showing portrait. and the same thing happening for Landscape to portrait the screen size is showing landscape like the figure shown in the link.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jjjx.png)

### manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bdb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bdb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams .FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.birthdayview);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(myVideoView);
    try{
    String vidpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.birthday;
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vidpath));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.start();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.bdb.MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/birthdayview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </VideoView>
```

any solution/suggestions to solve this problem? Thank you so much :)

Comment: `... Crashing of screen size...` What does it mean?

Comment: i don't know what word exactly to be used but the problem can be identified at the picture, just click the link enter image description here.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in your manifest, you took responsibility for handling all these changes. Yet, you have not implemented `onConfigurationChanged` to handle the configuration change for your layout. You should manually change the size of the `VideoView`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    doLayout();
}

private void doLayout() {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
        == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // do PORTRAIT stuff
    } else {
        // do LANDSCAPE stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: so u mean, i will make two layouts? one for portrait and another for landscape?

Comment: No, you don't need two layouts. You just need to set size for the VideoView; because its dimensions should change to reflect the orientation change. Post the xml layout files, so that we can give proper advice.